# Хелп! Не могу связаться с бд

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста по какой причине не получается записать данные из массива в таблицу? Ошибок никаких не выдает, но запись не происходит, просто выводит NO.

```
    <? 
    $result = $_POST;

    $your_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["mail"]);
    $tel_num = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tel"]);
    $about_yourself = htmlspecialchars($_POST["about"]);

    if($result["name"]=="")
      echo "Input name please ;)";


    if ($result["mail"]=="")
      echo "Input mail please ;)";


    if($result["tel"]=="" or !(is_numeric($result["tel"])))
      echo "Input tel please ;)";


    if($result["about"]=="")
      echo "Talking about yourselft ;)";

    $connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'f-moda_db');

    if ($connection == false){
       echo "Connection problem";
       echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

    $done = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `requests`(`name`, `mail`, 
    `telephone`, `AboutMe`) VALUES ({$result['name']}, {$result['mail']}, 
    {$result['tel']}, {$result['about']})");

    if ($done == true)
    echo "Succeful";
    else
    echo "NO !";
    mysqli_error($connection);
    ?>
```

Comment: `Ошибок никаких не выдает` - а если так `if (!$done) {
        printf("Ошибка: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
    }` ?  .......... а если в начале файла написать `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com         Выдало вот это )

Comment: Ну вот, а говоришь ошибок не выдает))  чини свой запрос... например вокруг строковых значений должны быть кавычки которых у тебя нет

Comment: Мне конечно дико неудобно, но все равно врубиться не могу). Вы имели ввиду вот эти кавычки?                                                               
      $done = 
      mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `requests`(`name`, `mail`, 
     `telephone`, `AboutMe`) VALUES ({"$result["name"]"},  
      {"$result["mail"]"}, {"$result["tel"]"}, {"$result["about"]"})");

Comment: `INSERT INTO \`requests\`(\`name\`, \`mail\`, 
\`telephone\`, \`AboutMe\`) VALUES ('{$result['name']}', '{$result['mail']}', 
'{$result['tel']}', '{$result['about']}')` .............. но вообще раз используешь mysqli, значит надо использовать и подготовленные выражения (как в ответе написано. тогда и проблем с кавычками не будет тоже

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо Алексей, вы маг и волшебник !!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас кавычек в запросе не хватает, если "вклеивать". Но, раз уж у Вас есть mysqli - почему бы не воспользоваться безопасной возможностью вставки любых данных?

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO `requests`(`name`, `mail`, `telephone`, `AboutMe`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bindParam('ssss',$result['name'],$result['mail'],$result['telephone'],$result['about']);
$done= $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь Александр, я даже и не знал, что в sqli есть специальные средства для этого, буду изучать )